# How do I execute first my custom error message before the first Traceback?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I made a program with restrictions with Tkinter and I created a custom error message wherein if the conditions for the restriction is met, then an error message box would pop up.

Now, my problem is that the message box only pops up after terminating my program, it doesn't get
executed while the program is still open, here's my code.

```
try:
    None

except:
    raise SyntaxError(messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Error message')
```

This is the output:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 1921, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\user1\PycharmProjects\Python Program\main.py", line 53, in
>
> command=lambda: equal(), relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)   File "C:\Users\user1\PycharmProjects\Python Porgram\main.py", line 32, in
> equal
> result = str(eval(expression))   File "", line 1
> */
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\user1\PycharmProjects\Python Program\main.py", line
> 171, in 
> raise SyntaxError(messagebox.showerror('Error', 'You cannot bundle two or more operations together.')) SyntaxError: ok

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: That's exactly what happens if you raise an exception and don't handle it. If you want to have a message box, create a message box.

Comment: In that case you shouldn't raise an exception, but instead call the message box when the exception occurs in `except` of a `try`/`except` block.

Comment: @NiltonMoura, Thanks, but I just can't quite understand the concept of the try/except blocks. Can you please show me how to implement that to fix my program?

Comment: Ok, could you please edit your question with the whole block in which you have the `raise SyntaxError`?

Comment: @NiltonMoura, I've edited it. There was no suitable code for the try block so I passed on None..

Comment: With `None` in your `try`, the line `raise` never runs. Are you sure this is your actual code that raised that exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    # Anything you want to do.
    # If in this block a SyntaxError happens, you'll
    # catch it with the line below and do whatever you want
    # instead of raising and actual exception.
except SyntaxError:
    messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Error message')
```

If you don't know what kinds of exceptions can be raised within your `try`, you can replace the `except SyntaxError:` with `except:`. But I recommend you to be explicit here with the exceptions. As exceptions arises, append the specific ones.